# In my code i am getting a name error saying the name 'sort' is not defined

Tags: python

```
import csv
import operator

form = input('If you would like to view form 1 please enter "1".If you would like to view form 2 please enter "2" and If you would like to view form 3 please enter "3"')
if form == "1":
   sort = input('If you would like the names sorted alphabetically enter "a".If you would like the scores sorted from highest to lowesr please enter "b" and If you would like the average scores sorted from highest to lowest please enter "c"')
if sort == "a":
    readfile = csv.reader(open("Form1.csv"), delimiter=",")
    sortedfile = sorted(readfile, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    file = open("Form1.csv", "a")
    for eachline in sortedfile:
        eachline.sort()
        print(eachline)
    file.close()
if sort == 'b':
    file = open('Form1.csv')
    readfile = csv.reader(file)
    for line in readfile:
        integers = (line[0:4])
        integers.sort(reverse = True)
        print(integers)
averages = []
if sort == 'c':
    file = open('Form1.csv')
    readfile = csv.reader(file)
    for line in readfile:
        values = (line[2:4])
        values = list(map(int, values))
        average = (sum(values)/len(values))
        averages.append(average)
        averages.sort(reverse = True)
        print(averages)

elif form == "2":
    sort = input('If you would like the names sorted alphabetically enter "a".If you would like the scores sorted from highest to lowesr please enter "b" and If you would like the average scores sorted from highest to lowest please enter "c"')
if sort == "a":
    readfile = csv.reader(open("Form2.csv"), delimiter=",")
    sortedfile = sorted(readfile, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    file = open("Form2.csv", "a")
    for eachline in sortedfile:
        eachline.sort()
        print(eachline)
    file.close()
if sort == 'b':
    file = open('Form2.csv')
    readfile = csv.reader(file)
    for line in readfile:
        integers = (line[0:4])
        integers.sort(reverse = True)
        print(integers)
averages = []
if sort == 'c':
    file = open('Form2.csv')
    readfile = csv.reader(file)
    for line in readfile:
        values = (line[2:4])
        values = list(map(int, values))
        average = (sum(values)/len(values))
        averages.append(average)
        averages.sort(reverse = True)
        print(averages)

elif form == "3":
    sort = input('If you would like the names sorted alphabetically enter "a".If you would like the scores sorted from highest to lowesr please enter "b" and If you would like the average scores sorted from highest to lowest please enter "c"')
if sort == "a":
    readfile = csv.reader(open("Form3.csv"), delimiter=",")
    sortedfile = sorted(readfile, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
    file = open("Form3.csv", "a")
    for eachline in sortedfile:
        eachline.sort()
        print(eachline)
    file.close()
if sort == 'b':
    file = open('Form3.csv')
    readfile = csv.reader(file)
    for line in readfile:
        integers = (line[0:4])
        integers.sort(reverse = True)
        print(integers)
averages = []
if sort == 'c':
    file = open('Form3.csv')
    readfile = csv.reader(file)
    for line in readfile:
        values = (line[2:4])
        values = list(map(int, values))
        average = (sum(values)/len(values))
        averages.append(average)
        averages.sort(reverse = True)
        print(averages)
```

Could you please tell me what i could do to solve this problem please.Thanks. I also have another problem when i give the response 1 to the first question and give the response a for the second question it prints out the names from all the from files however it is meant to input the names from form one only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if form is not "1" you don't define sort before your next if

```
if form == "1": 
   sort = input('If you would like the names sorted alphabetically enter "a".If you would like the scores sorted from highest to lowesr please enter "b" and If you would like the average scores sorted from highest to lowest please enter "c"')
if sort == "a": # not defined
```

If you want sort to have a default value set it before your if statements:

```
sort = "some default"
```

Or nest the `if's`:

```
if form == "1":
   sort = input('If you would like the names sorted alphabetically enter "a".If you would like the scores sorted from highest to lowesr please enter "b" and If you would like the average scores sorted from highest to lowest please enter "c"')
    if sort == "a":
         ....
```

You should probably just verify the user makes a valid choice before going any further:

```
while True:
    form = input('If you would like to view form 1 please enter "1".If you would like to view form 2 please enter "2" and If you would like to view form 3 please enter "3"')
    if form not in {"1","2","3"}:
        print("Invalid choice")
    else:
        break
```

sort also cannot be more than one value so use if/elif's:

```
if sort == "a":
   ....

elif sort == "b":
    ....
```

You can remove a lot of your repeated code, opening the file in one place for each block, you should use elif's and nest the sort if/elifs inside the if form ==:

```
averages = []
while True:
    form = input(
        'If you would like to view form 1 please enter "1".If you would like to view form 2 please enter "2" and If you would like to view form 3 please enter "3"')
    if form not in {"1", "2", "3"}:
        print("Invalid choice")
    else:
        break

if form == "1":
    sort = input(
        'If you would like the names sorted alphabetically enter "a".If you would like the scores sorted from highest to lowesr please enter "b" and If you would like the average scores sorted from highest to lowest please enter "c"')
    with  open("Form1.csv") as f:
        read_file = csv.reader(f)
        if sort == "a":
            sorted_file = sorted(read_file)
            for each_line in sorted_file:
                each_line.sort()
                print(each_line)
        elif sort == 'b':
            for line in read_file:
                integers = (line[0:4])
                integers.sort(reverse=True)
                print(integers)
        elif sort == 'c':
            for line in read_file:
                values = (line[2:4])
                values = list(map(int, values))
                average = (sum(values) / len(values))
                averages.append(average)
            averages.sort(reverse=True)
            print(averages)      
elif form == "2":
    sort = input('If you would like the names sorted alphabetically enter "a".If you would like the scores sorted from highest to lowesr please enter "b" and If you would like the average scores sorted from highest to lowest please enter "c"')
    with open('Form2.csv') as f:
        read_file = csv.reader(f)
    if sort == "a":
        sorted_file = sorted(read_file)
        for each_line in sorted_file:
            each_line.sort()
            print(each_line)
    elif sort == 'b':
        for line in read_file:
            integers = (line[0:4])
            integers.sort(reverse = True)
            print(integers)

    elif sort == 'c':
        for line in read_file:
            values = (line[2:4])
            values = list(map(int, values))
            average = (sum(values)/len(values))
            averages.append(average)
            averages.sort(reverse = True)
            print(averages)
elif form == "3":
    sort = input(
        'If you would like the names sorted alphabetically enter "a".If you would like the scores sorted from highest to lowesr please enter "b" and If you would like the average scores sorted from highest to lowest please enter "c"')
    with open("Form3.csv") as f:
        read_file = csv.reader(f)
        if sort == "a":
            sorted_file = sorted(read_file)
            for each_line in sorted_file:
                each_line.sort()
                print(each_line)
        elif sort == 'b':
            for line in read_file:
                integers = (line[0:4])
                integers.sort(reverse=True)
                print(integers)
        elif sort == 'c':
            for line in read_file:
                values = (line[2:4])
                values = list(map(int, values))
                average = (sum(values) / len(values))
                averages.append(average)
            averages.sort(reverse=True)
            print(averages)
```

You might also want to apply the form while loop logic to each sort, using a function with a while loop to make sure the user picks a correct option.

Comment: @abi Although it is polite to thank users for helping you, please refrain from saying "Thanks" or "+1" in the comments. This keeps Stack Overflow clutter-free.

Comment: @abi, what is the issue?

Comment: @abi, I cleaned up your code a bit, not fully sure what all of it is doing but the logic should be a lot closer to what you are trying to do

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried using your code however it did not work but im not really worried about the average scores now. every time i enter a specific form and i respond to how i want it sorted it uses the data from all the form csv files. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @abi,  I missed a  part of the code, you will only read one file based on what input you give for sort

Comment: @PadraicCunningham    what could i do so that the code only uses the form file the user asks for? By user i mean the person qwho runs the code and responds to it.

Comment: It should already be doing that, first the user picks a form, then they pick an option

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i received a error by using the code. "read_file = csv.reader(f)
NameError: name 'csv' is not defined"

Comment: You need to add the import. import csv

Comment: @PadraicCunningham i did try that however this popped up "line 51, in <module>
    for line in read_file:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file."